# Shrinking log files on development

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008-r2, sql-server-2012, transaction-log

I've been looking at getting some disk space back on some of our development machines.
These are machines that are not being backed up, not being developed on directly, and not being maintained particularly well.
Any recovery is done from PRD or PRE-PRD to the DEV environment, nothing on this particular DEV environment is critical.

The recovery models on these databases has to remain on `FULL` because it was so ordained (despite no actual backups being taken).
As these databases in some cases have been around for quite some time without backups, I'm looking into a proper way to shrink their logs.

I've found two approaches that might serve the purpose:

`BACKUP LOG [databasename] TO DISK=’NUL:’`

Followed by shrinking the log.

Or:

`ALTER DATABASE [databasename] SET RECOVERY SIMPLE;`
`ALTER DATABASE [databasename] SET RECOVERY FULL;`

Followed by shrinking the log.

My actual questions:
What are the differences between these two approaches?
Is there something I'm missing / overlooking?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For this scenario I prefer the method of doing (I added `WITH NO_COMPRESSION` just in case the server default setting is to use Compression since there is little point in using extra CPU when the resulting file isn't going to take up any space anyway):

```sql
BACKUP LOG [databasename] TO DISK = 'NUL:' WITH NO_COMPRESSION;
```

The reason I prefer this method over switching to `SIMPLE` and then back to `FULL` is that it doesn't change the overall backup process. This way you can have more consistency between your environments. It also allows you to have a testing environment for your backup process because it isn't different than what you have in Production. And if sending the file to **NUL:** presents too much of a difference, then just send it to a folder where the backup file can be deleted.

Flipping to `SIMPLE` and then back to `FULL` makes it harder to test `DIFF`erential backups since you need to have a `FULL` backup first. So if you do a FULL backup once a week and DIFF the rest of the week, flipping to `SIMPLE` and then back to `FULL` would work if done just prior to the weekly `FULL` backup, but not at any other time during the week. On the other hand, taking the `LOG` backup and either directing it to **NUL:** or deleting the backup file can be done at any point during the week.

Also, taking the `LOG` backup and either directing it to **NUL:** or deleting the backup file allows you to maintain a pre-grown LOG / **.ldf** file. And at that point you can use [DBCC SHRINKFILE](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms189493.aspx) to enforce a maximum initial-size of the empty LOG file and not get stuck with a file that grew A LOT due to reindexing or something else.

PLEASE NOTE that getting rid of your LOG backups means that you will not be able to restore to points in time between your FULL / DIFF backups. Of course, if you don't have FULL / DIFF backups in the first place, then this is a moot point.

Comment: Yes, just be very aware that if you send your log backups to NUL, there is no hope of restoring to any point in time between full backups, if that is ever going to be a concern in the dev environment.

Comment: @AaronBertrand I have updated my answer to reflect that.

Answer (score 0):

when you do `BACKUP LOG [databasename] TO DISK=’NUL:’`, it is like taking a backup to a drive which never exists, its just like a normal log backup but it actual does not back the log and fakes in a way, by not occupying any space.

This is not all a good practice, but since you said this being DEV and not critical you may approach, only when you are in a situation where there is hardly any space on the drive and can bring the system down.

In case you are not that bad on space, you should follow the second approach of taking the log backup first, and then changing recovery models from FULL to Simple and back to FULL accordingly.

Considering , Point in recovery time is what is not a concern here you can,

```
ALTER DATABASE DBNAME SET RECOVERY SIMPLE;


USE DBNAME;
GO
CHECKPOINT;
GO
CHECKPOINT;
GO

DBCC SHRINKFILE(DB_log, 512);-- 512 is something you can adjust accordingly
GO
```

And then adjust the file setting/growth accordingly

```
USE [master];
GO
ALTER DATABASE DBNAME 
  MODIFY FILE
  (NAME = DB_log, SIZE = 520 MB, FILEGROWTH = 256MB);-- 512 and 256 should be adjusted as analysed from database growth events
GO
```

In addition to above , please read Aaron's answer [Why Does the Transaction Log Keep Growing or Run Out of Space?](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/29829/why-does-the-transaction-log-keep-growing-or-run-out-of-space) for better understanding

Comment: You just made me realize that I'll be impacting the DEV by decreasing performance as I increase the amount of log file growths... So I should probably be adding a part that only shrinks it to 25% the size of the data file. Why however do you consider the backup to `NUL.` as inherently worse?

Comment: Backup to `NUL` is not a bad idea if you don't ever care about recovering the database in question.  Its a great way to clear VLFs without setting the database to simple recovery in preparation for shrinking the log file since nothing is actually written anywhere... the only IO requirement is reading VLFs that are waiting a log backup.

Comment: @MaxVernon Is there any place I could find some documentation about the way backup to `NUL` clear's the VLFs? I've tried looking but I failed in my search.

Comment: BACKUP LOG clears VLFs regardless of *where* the backup is targeted.